# Regular expression for highlighting words in quotes int qt5

Tags: regex, qt, syntax-highlighting, qt5

I use QHighlighter class, and used regExp to highlight words in quotes:

```
void Highlighter::highlightBlock(const QString &text)
{
    QRegExp expr("\"(.*?)\"");
    int index = expr.indexIn(text);
    while(index >=0)
    {
        int length = expr.matchedLength();
        setFormat(index, length, Qt::red);
        index = expr.indexIn(text, index+length);
    }

}
```

It doesn't work. Work this:

```
"\".*\""
```

But it highlights unnecessary. What regular expression is correct?

Comment: Please provide a sample string that doesn't match what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you want to highlight just everything between quotes ``"\"([^\"]*)\""`` or do you want to highlight single words ``"\"(\\w)*\""``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just higlight everything between quotes

```
QRegExp("\"([^\"]*)\"");
```

highlight single words (run in loop with offset to match words)

```
QRegExp("\"(\\w)*\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How to match words in quotes:

```
('|")[^\1]*?\1
```

#### Example:

http://regex101.com/r/iF5aA1